# How to find a battery health?

Tags: batteries, capacity

How to find a battery health/wear for rechargeable batteries? Especially for the most commonly used AA NiMH and proprietary Li-Ion or Li-Pol batteries?

How to find out a percentage of their original capacity?

If there is a need to measure a full discharge, how to do it quick and easy?

Answer (score 2):

Run a capacity test.  That means charging fully, then discharging to near empty, meanwhile measuring the energy and/or charge delivered.

Comment: +1 And repeat periodically as the battery ages. Or the ambient temperature changes. Or the load current changes.

Comment: How to do it with as little equipment as possible? 
How to discharge it the most quickly without any negative effects on it? 
How to measure the discharging without the need to write down the U/I all the time in the process?

Comment: If you discharge a battery quickly then your data will only apply to actual applications where the battery is discharged quickly. The available capacity is a function of the discharge rate. Somehow you must record the I/V values or you won't have any way to determine the remaining capacity.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to use a Fuel Gauge such as the [bq series from TI](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/power-management/battery-fuel-gauge-products.page) or another manufacturer. Please note that compared to measuring voltage, this approach is more involved but not that difficult. It is considerably more accurate than other solutions.

These fuel gauges learn the battery after a few charge/discharge cycles and can tell you the battery state. Please note that this is very chemistry specific.

You don't want to have to charge and discharge it just to test it. Using a fuel gauge can give you the information of battery life during normal use (after the learning cycles).

The devices use typically I2C communication for both programming as well as access and they are full of registers that tell you time remaining, battery health, current charging or discharging, etc. Its basically the way Cell phones and other devices give you the battery status. This also takes into account temperature and other effects that are difficult to take into account just by a few charge/discharge cycles.